# Using Filterable in a Custom Adapter for AutoComplete

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-filterable

I'm having trouble showing autocomplete suggestions in an AutoCompleteTextView.

Here is the TextView:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/atvAddContact"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white" />
```

This is how I set the Adapter:

```
ArrayList<Contacto> list = cc.getContactosList("");
ContactosAdapter2 adapter = new ContactosAdapter2(this, R.layout.contact_list_item, list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And now for the tricky part, this is my Adapter which is a copy of a fully working adapter for a ListView (with the same list items) with the exception that it implements Filterable, which right now does not filter and should show all results, but it shows nothing. The ArrayList set to the adapter is full of items, so the data is there.

My getFilter() method though is never called and I don't know why, same with the getView.

I already tried a simple autocomplete with a String array and it worked but I'm having trouble getting my head around this custom Auto Complete with Custom Objects, any help is welcome!!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.android.proj.R;
import com.android.proj.datas.Contacto;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ContactosAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<Contacto> implements Filterable{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
ArrayList<Contacto> data = new ArrayList<Contacto>();

public ContactosAdapter2(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contacto> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() 
{
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() 
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) 
        {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null) 
            {
                filterResults.values = data;
                filterResults.count = data.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) 
        {
            if(results != null && results.count > 0) 
            {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ContactoHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ContactoHolder();
        holder.contactoNombre = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvContactoNombre);
        holder.contactoInfo = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvContactoInfo);
        holder.contactoImg = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ivContactoImg);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ContactoHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Contacto ap = data.get(position);
    holder.contactoNombre.setText(ap.getNombre());
    byte[] baImage = ap.getBaImage();

    if (baImage == null)
        holder.contactoImg.setImageURI(ap.getPhoto());
    else
        holder.contactoImg.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baImage, 0, baImage.length));

    if (ap.getNumber().length() > 0 && ap.getNumber().charAt(0) == '#')
        holder.contactoInfo.setText(ap.getNumber().substring(1, ap.getNumber().length()));
    else
        holder.contactoInfo.setText(ap.getNumber());

    return row;
}

static class ContactoHolder
{
    TextView contactoNombre;
    TextView contactoInfo;
    ImageView contactoImg;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> This was indeed very silly but I wasn't indicating which adapter to use for the AutoCompleteTextView, the missing code was:

```
atvAddContact.setAdapter(adapter);
```